# WSO2: How to get user access token by API in a SSO setting environment with API-M and Identity server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Environment :

- wso2 API-M + wso2 Identity server (Key manager) and they shared the
  same user store.
- 2 service providers(publisher and store) and 2 identity
  providers(Google and Facebook) in the carbon.super tenant.
- APIM SSO service is enabled and issuer IDs follow above.
- Enable OAuth2.0 users(Google and Facebook) to login.
- 3 tenants (carbon.super , TA and TB) in the environment.
- Publisher SP and Store SP are both in SaaS mode.

Question:

How can user get his access token by API with his account and password?

I try to refer the document : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Token+API

but it seems need consumer key and secret, is there other way without consumer key pair to get user access token?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to have consumer/key secret pair to get access token. For user authentication you can use different grant flows(SAML2, Authorization code etc) but to verify client OAuth application you must pass application details(because you can have multiple applications in system and Oauth server need to know what application you are referring).

Thanks

sanjeewa.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)